# Поиск элемента в массиве объектов JS

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты, поиск

Имеется объект data. Необходимо получить "name", зная "key". К примеру, если key = '1.002', нужно получить name = 'Это имя нужно получить'. Уровень вложенности неограничен.

```js
const data = [{
    key: '1.001',
    data: {
      id: '1.001',
      name: 'qwe',
    },
    children: [{
        key: '1.002',
        data: {
          id: '1.002',
          name: 'Это имя нужно получить',
        },
        children: null,
      },
      {
        key: '1.003',
        data: {
          id: '1.003',
          name: 'qwe',
        },
        children: null,
      },
      {
        key: '1.004',
        data: {
          id: '1.004',
          name: 'qwe',
        },
        children: [{
            key: '1.005',
            data: {
              id: '1.005',
              name: 'qwe',
            },
            children: null,
          },
          {
            key: '1.006',
            data: {
              id: '1.006',
              name: 'qwe',
            },
            children: null,
          },
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    key: '2.001',
    data: {
      id: '2.001',
      name: 'qwe',
    },
    children: [{
        key: '2.002',
        data: {
          id: '2.002',
          name: 'qwe',
        },
        children: null,
      },
      {
        key: '2.003',
        data: {
          id: '2.003',
          name: 'qwe',
        },
        children: null,
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы найти какой-то элемент, достаточно просто обойти все элементы.

Для этого можно поместить все доступные узлы в массив.

Брать из этого массива по одному узлу и проверять, подходит он под условие или нет.
Если подходит, то поиск закончен - достаточно вернуть данный узел и взять нужное поле.

Если не подходит и есть дочерние узлы - нужно добавить их в массив доступных узлов.

Если добавлять в начало - будет обход в глубину, если добавлять в конец - обход в ширину.

Пример:

```js
const data = [{
    key: '1.001',
    data: {
      id: '1.001',
      name: 'qwe',
    },
    children: [{
        key: '1.002',
        data: {
          id: '1.002',
          name: 'Это имя нужно получить',
        },
        children: null,
      },
      {
        key: '1.003',
        data: {
          id: '1.003',
          name: 'qwe',
        },
        children: null,
      },
      {
        key: '1.004',
        data: {
          id: '1.004',
          name: 'qwe',
        },
        children: [{
            key: '1.005',
            data: {
              id: '1.005',
              name: 'qwe',
            },
            children: null,
          },
          {
            key: '1.006',
            data: {
              id: '1.006',
              name: 'qwe',
            },
            children: null,
          },
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    key: '2.001',
    data: {
      id: '2.001',
      name: 'qwe',
    },
    children: [{
        key: '2.002',
        data: {
          id: '2.002',
          name: 'qwe',
        },
        children: null,
      },
      {
        key: '2.003',
        data: {
          id: '2.003',
          name: 'qwe',
        },
        children: null,
      },
    ]
  }
]

function findByKey(arr, key) {
  var nodes = arr.slice();
  while (nodes.length) {
    const node = nodes.shift();

    if (node.key === key) return node;

    if (node.children) {
      nodes.push(...node.children);
    }
  }
}

console.log(findByKey(data, '1.002')?.data?.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [{
    key: '1.001',
    data: {
      id: '1.001',
      name: 'qwe',
    },
    children: [{
        key: '1.002',
        data: {
          id: '1.002',
          name: 'Это имя нужно получить',
        },
        children: null,
      },
      {
        key: '1.003',
        data: {
          id: '1.003',
          name: 'qwe',
        },
        children: null,
      },
      {
        key: '1.004',
        data: {
          id: '1.004',
          name: 'qwe',
        },
        children: [{
            key: '1.005',
            data: {
              id: '1.005',
              name: 'qwe',
            },
            children: null,
          },
          {
            key: '1.006',
            data: {
              id: '1.006',
              name: 'qwe',
            },
            children: null,
          },
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    key: '2.001',
    data: {
      id: '2.001',
      name: 'qwe',
    },
    children: [{
        key: '2.002',
        data: {
          id: '2.002',
          name: 'qwe',
        },
        children: null,
      },
      {
        key: '2.003',
        data: {
          id: '2.003',
          name: 'qwe2003',
        },
        children: null,
      },
    ]
  }
]

const getNameByKey = (array, key) => {
  if (array) {
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (array[i].key === key) {
        return array[i].data.name
      } else {
        const childrenByKey = getNameByKey(array[i].children, key)
        if (childrenByKey) return childrenByKey
      }
    }
  }
  return null
}

console.log(getNameByKey(data, "2.003"))
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас данные имеют древовидную структуру, следовательно, можно использовать алгоритмы для обхода деревьев. Например, обход в глубину. Однако у вас может быть множество корневых элементов, поэтому применим функцию ко всем узлам и вернем преобразованный результат.

```
const data = [{
    key: '1.001',
    data: {
      id: '1.001',
      name: 'qwe',
    },
    children: [{
        key: '1.002',
        data: {
          id: '1.002',
          name: 'Это имя нужно получить',
        },
        children: null,
      },
      {
        key: '1.003',
        data: {
          id: '1.003',
          name: 'qwe',
        },
        children: null,
      },
      {
        key: '1.004',
        data: {
          id: '1.004',
          name: 'qwe',
        },
        children: [{
            key: '1.005',
            data: {
              id: '1.005',
              name: 'qwe',
            },
            children: null,
          },
          {
            key: '1.006',
            data: {
              id: '1.006',
              name: 'qwe',
            },
            children: null,
          },
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    key: '2.001',
    data: {
      id: '2.001',
      name: 'qwe',
    },
    children: [{
        key: '2.002',
        data: {
          id: '2.002',
          name: 'qwe',
        },
        children: null,
      },
      {
        key: '2.003',
        data: {
          id: '2.003',
          name: 'qwe',
        },
        children: null,
      },
    ]
  }
];

const findName = (tree, key) => {
  if (tree.key === key) {
    return tree.data.name;
  }
  const children = tree.children;
  if (children !== null) {
    return children.flatMap((node) => findName(node, key));
  }
  return [];
};

const result = String(data.flatMap((rootNode) => findName(rootNode, '1.002')));

console.log(result); // Это имя нужно получить
```